# How to list available SQL Server instance in a network?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

I want to write a program that allows user to select one SQL Server instances in an network. How can I list available instances in a C# program?

Addition questions: How can I know that a database is currently mirroring? Is there a way to know what instance is it's partner and it's witness?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help http://www.zuhaib.in/how-to/c-sharp-obtain-list-of-sql-server-instances